# How to use a vector of structs in a vector structs in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a vector of trains, where each train needs a vector of pairs.

If I run the code outside of main(), I get these errors:

```
naive-bayes.cpp:17:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    vector<pair> pairs;

naive-bayes.cpp:17:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Inside `main()`, I get these errors:

```
naive-bayes.cpp:22:15: error: template argument for 'template<class>
class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::pair'
    vector<pair> pairs;

naive-bayes.cpp:22:15: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class> class std::allocator'

naive-bayes.cpp:22:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Here is the code:

```
struct pair {
    int index;
    int value;
};

struct trains {
    string label;
    vector<pair> pairs;
};
```

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`? And are you `using namespace std`?

Comment: And, if you have `using namespace std`, you are asking for trouble if you ever `#include <utility>` since there is a templated `std::pair`.    Even worse, with some implementations, some standard header files include each other even when the standard doesn't require it.

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is not C++ is not C!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is probably due to `using namespace std;`.

There is a `std::pair` type in the standard library.

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct pair {
    int index;
    int value;
};

struct trains {
    std::string label;
    std::vector<pair> pairs;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a full program example to play with, all I can really point out is that your local `pair` declaration is likely getting confused with `std::pair`.  Change your definition of `struct pair` to be `struct mypair`.

Comment: `struct mypair` and `mypair` will be equivalent in C++.

Comment: @Peter - Is that true?  Oops!  Just tried that out here and you are indeed correct.  Thanks for the correction.  Will update

Comment: yep, it's second solution :)